# Where do I store the clients subscribed to topics in a MQTT server?

Tags: c, server, mqtt, iot

So I'm trying to build a MQTT server using C. Now as you know, MQTT has a publish subscribe model where clients subscribe to topics and other clients publish to topics.

So whenever a client connects to my MQTT broker and subscribes to a topic, where do I store the corresponding topic name and client? Do I create a hashmap containing topic names as keys and clients subscribed to them as values? Or is there any other way to do it?

Also do I store this in memory or in a database? Which one would be more efficient?

Thanks

Comment: This sounds very like a homework question

Comment: @hardillb I tried to do my homework but did not find any substantial info. Maybe you could give me some pointers?